# Javascript firebase:read username using once then method

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my firebase looks like this

```
user1
    |--Name
     --ID

user2
    |--Name
     --ID

user3
    |--Name
     --ID
```

i have tried

```
    return firebase.database().ref('/User3').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      var username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().Name) || 'Anonymous';
     alert(username)
    });
```

it returns me Anonymous but provides data in console

Comment: Did you log snapshot? You shoud use .catch() to see the error too.

Comment: it provides JSON data in console but says anonymous

Comment: ok thank you i have figured out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `snapshot.val()` will return `null` ([API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val)) if there is no data at the location of your query.  So that means you have no data at `/User3`.  In your schema, you have `user3` but no `User3`.  Realtime Database is case sensitive, so maybe that's the problem.

Comment: In any event, if the snapshot is null, there is no data.

Comment: it is providing data  in console